# Lattice iCECube2 cannot find clock in .sdc file

Tags: fpga, timing-analysis, lattice

I've tried a zillion different ways to get the lattice iCECube2 tools to find a generated clock.
How do I specify the .sdc file to see the output of `baudgeninst`, which is used as a 115,200 baud clock to the test `junk` register?  I think this is causing problems later in the design where the tool can't place a not-very-complicated block of logic.  I've removed the larger block from below code.  The code below happens to build, but it still can't find the clock.  When I include the larger block, the code fails at placement.  I suspect not knowing about the baud clock is the reason.

top.sv:

```
module drotop(input  rstb, 
            input  clk,  // board clk
            input  dclk, // dro clk
            input  ddat, // dro in
            output dclkout,
            output ddatout,
            output tx,   // uart out
            input  rx,   // uart in
            output debug,
            output [7:0] dbus,
            output [7:0] led
            );

    logic [7:0] junk;
    logic baudclk;

    baudgen baudgeninst(clk, baudclk);

    always @(posedge baudclk, negedge rstb) begin
        if (!rstb) junk <= 8'h0;
        else if (baudclk) junk <= junk + 1;
    end
endmodule

module baudgen(input clkin, output clkout);
    // From https://www.fpga4fun.com/SerialInterface2.html

    parameter freq = 12_000_000; // 12MHz
    parameter baud = 115200;
    parameter width = 16;
    parameter incr = ((baud<<(width-4))+(freq>>5)) / (freq>>5);

    logic [width:0] acc = 16'b0;
    always @(posedge clkin)
        acc <= acc + incr;

    assign clkout = acc[width];
endmodule
```

prj.sdc:

```
# Clocks 
create_clock -period 83.333    [ get_ports clk ]  ;## 12.0 MHz

# I've tried various versions of this type of thing with get_pins, get_nets, get_ports, 
# identifier names in top level, identifier names between modules, net names inside the
# the module as found in reports, vertical bar '|', slash '/', curly braces, etc.

# Error looks like:
# "c:/lattice/constraints/prj.sdc":11:0:11:0|Clock source [get_nets {baudgen|acc_derived_clock[16]}] not found in netlist: create_generated_clock -source [get_ports clk] -divide_by 104 [get_nets {baudgen|acc_derived_clock[16]}]
create_generated_clock -source [ get_ports clk ] -divide_by 104 [get_nets {baudgen|acc_derived_clock[16]}]
create_generated_clock -source [ get_ports clk ] -divide_by 104 [get_nets {drotop|baudclk}]
create_generated_clock -source [ get_ports clk ] -divide_by 104 [get_pins {baudgen|clkout}]
create_generated_clock -source [ get_ports clk ] -divide_by 104 [get_pins {baudgeninst|clkout}]
```